# How to set responsive height to react-table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-table

I use react-table: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/v6 and also use bootstrap. My table is adaptive to mobile devices in width but not in height. How to make it responsive in height?

That is the quantity of shown rows must be the same in initial screen and screen with changed height
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.innerHeight` to get the window `screen` size and store it in a `state` variable and pass the `height` value stored in the `state` to `table`.Add event listeners `window.addEventListener` for responsive height changes in table

Comment: could you provide the code itself how to addEventlistener in react component and how to write it to my table?